# How to grep exact matching special characters from file?

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell, grep

I have a file like below:

```
A   4   ab,cc,ab,bc
B   6   x,xx,y,%,%%,\,\\
AB  0
```

I need to grep special characters from the third column from the file and return its corresponding first column. For e.g., I need to grep '%' and it would return me B (it's corresponding first column)

I have tried using:

```
grep -w "%" file1
```

But it would return me % and %% both. Like:

```
B   6   x,xx,y,%,%%,\,\\
```

Where %,%% are highlighted. I only want to grep the exact word/character as searched. In the above case it should only try to find '%' and not '%%'. This approach works fine with words as from grep manual grep -w works when it finds lines containing matches that form whole words.

I also tried using it with

```
grep -wP "%" file1
```

for Perl like pattern. But did not return anything.

Can anyone suggest how can I grep exact matching special characters? This however does not solve the problem for special characters '\'. Backslash can be escaped and handled. But for the other special characters I need to find a solution.

---

OK. Slight change required here in my question. All the answers given here are great and work very well according to my question. But maybe I missed another requirement here. My bad. As all the solutions here used '%' as test parameter, but '%' was only my example. What I really was looking for is more of a generalized solution working for all the words/characters. I'll give an example. Consider the file below:

```
A   4   a    b,c            c,ab,bc
          ^          ^
          ^     couple of tabs here
      multiple spaces here
B   6   x,xx,y,%,%%,\,\\
AB  0
```

What I mean to say is that the file can contain any sort of characters, words (separated by single/multiple spaces, tabs, etc.) and also any special characters (including single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash ()). These three needs to be specially handled as they are kind of reserved.

I apologize for missing this part before, but I hope the kind of solution I am looking for here would be clear now.

I would vote up for all the working solutions for special characters. But it doesn't allow me to (less reputation). But would there be a general solution? or if I can separate words(letters & numbers) and special characters by some if condition in shell script maybe?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

What about `awk`

```
$ awk '/%/{print $1}' inputFile
B
```

---

To match exact `%` in file, you can use lookarounds

```
$ grep -o '(?<!%)%(?!%)' input
```

- `(?<!%)` Negeative look behind. Asserts that `%` is not presceded by `%`
- `(?!%)` Negative look ahead. Asserts that the `%` is not followed by `%`

Answer (score 2):

Using perl from command line,

```
perl -nE 'say /(\S+)/ if /%/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extended match:

```
$ grep -P '(?<=[\s|,])%(?=[,$])' file
B   6   x,xx,y,%,%%,\,\\
               ^
               highlighted
```

This will just match if it is surrounded by either space or `,` and `,` or end of line.

#### Explanation

```
grep -P '(?<=[\s|,])%(?=[,$])'
```

- `-P` make `grep` use extended Perl regexp.
- `(?<=X)` means: check if there is `X` before.
- `[\s|,]` means: either a space character or a comma.
- `(?=Y)` means: check if there is `Y` after the match.
- `[,$]` means: either a comma or the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using perl, with autosplit by line - this splits fields on whitespace into an zero indexed array **@F**. I then print the first field (**$F[0]**) if the 3rd field (**$F[3]**) matches the regex pattern

Using negated character class to match just one % surrounded by things that are not a %. You could match on , if you're always looking for a comma separated field. If you don't know the delimiters many other answers have given you some examples of lookahead/lookbehind expressions

```
$ perl -lane 'print $F[0] if $F[2] =~ "[^%]%[^%]" ' < file1 
B
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep with `-P` parameter.

```
$ grep -oP '^\S+(?=\s+\S+\s+\S*(?<!%)%(?!%)\S*)' file
B
```

Example:

```
$ cat hi
A   4   ab,cc,ab,bc
B   6   x,xx,y,%,%%,\,\\
AB  0   
C   6   x,xx,y,%%
$ grep -oP '^\S+(?=\s+\S+\s+\S*(?<!%)%(?!%)\S*)' hi
B
```